# Problems implementing scroll reveal

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I want to have various types of transitions in my page. For example, I want the title to come from top to bottom while the last element of my page comes from bottom to top.
My javascript adds the class shown whenever the element is on screen.
But, if the element is moved (for example) -100px down to get back to 0px with the TranslateY, and this -100px pushes it off screen the animation doesn't start.
I don't know if the problem is my javascript or the use of the TranslateY. I don't want to use external libraries.

My javascript code:

```
// questa funzione serve a determinare se gli items osservati sono sullo schermo (utile per animazioni)
var elementiDaOsservare = document.querySelectorAll('.osservato');
var callback = function(items) {
    items.forEach((item) => {
        var position = item.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (item.isIntersecting) {
            item.target.classList.add("mostrato");
        } else if (position.top > 0) { // rimuove la classe mostrato solo se l'item si trova nella parte non visibile superiore dello schermo
            item.target.classList.remove("mostrato");
        }
    });
}
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
elementiDaOsservare.forEach((element) => {
    observer.observe(element);
});
```

Comment: You should consider a working snippit that recreates the issue rather than a snip of code without functionality.

Comment: I apologize for my bad question. I didn't even remember doing it. It happened after a long coding marathon, I was exhausted. The problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

The problem was easier to fix than expected. I just created various cases for the transition types and removed the px distance of the translateY:

```
const transitionT = document.querySelectorAll(".transitionT");
const transitionB = document.querySelectorAll(".transitionB");
const transitionL = document.querySelectorAll(".transitionL");
const transitionR = document.querySelectorAll(".transitionR");

function reveal() {
    transitionT.forEach(item => {
        var revealTop = item.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var revealPoint = 100;
        if (revealTop < windowHeight - revealPoint) item.classList.add("mostrato");
        else item.classList.remove("mostrato");
    });
    transitionB.forEach(item => {
        var revealTop = item.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var revealPoint = 100;
        if (revealTop < windowHeight + revealPoint) item.classList.add("mostrato");
        else item.classList.remove("mostrato");
    });
    transitionL.forEach(item => {
        var revealTop = item.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        if (revealTop < windowHeight) item.classList.add("mostrato");
        else item.classList.remove("mostrato");
    });
    transitionR.forEach(item => {
        var revealTop = item.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        if (revealTop < windowHeight) item.classList.add("mostrato");
        else item.classList.remove("mostrato");
    });
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(reveal);
transitionT.forEach((element) => {
    observer.observe(element);
});
transitionB.forEach((element) => {
    observer.observe(element);
});
transitionL.forEach((element) => {
    observer.observe(element);
});
transitionR.forEach((element) => {
    observer.observe(element);
});
```